# Filling name accounts

Tags: java, design-patterns

I think the content is too large and I am deeply think about how to refactor it. Does anyone have good advice on refactoring it?

```
List<AccountEntity> fillNameAccounts = agentDao.getAgentListByIds(accountIdList);
    for (T bean : results)
    {
        for (AccountEntity entity : fillNameAccounts)
        {
            String chineseName = entity.getChineseName();
            String firstName = entity.getFirstName();
            String fillName = StringUtils.isBlank(chineseName) ? firstName : chineseName;
            String entityId = entity.getId().toString();
            if (bean instanceof AgentPostResponseBean)
            {
                if (StringUtils.equals(((AgentPostResponseBean) bean).getParentId(), entityId))
                {
                    ((AgentPostResponseBean) bean).setParentName(fillName);
                }
                if (StringUtils.equals(((AgentPostResponseBean) bean).getPosterId(), entityId))
                {
                    ((AgentPostResponseBean) bean).setPosterName(fillName);
                }
            }
            else if (bean instanceof ImportAgentPostResponseBean)
            {

                if (StringUtils.equals(((ImportAgentPostResponseBean) bean).getParentId(), entityId))
                {
                    ((ImportAgentPostResponseBean) bean).setParentName(fillName);
                }
                if (StringUtils.equals(((ImportAgentPostResponseBean) bean).getPosterId(), entityId))
                {
                    ((ImportAgentPostResponseBean) bean).setPosterName(fillName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you take an action depending on class type of `bean`, so I would recommend you to implement a Visitor Pattern, because it is not god practice to use `instanceof` and because Visitor Pattern lets you growth your code without coupling.

My answer is more complex than previous, but it will give you more flexibility. What if you want to do more things than `setNameForEntity`? or what if you wnat to implement more concrete classes? Visitor Pattern will suite this needs.

Now, here comes how I would do the refactor. First, create an abstract class (or an interface) as base class for beans, like `AgentPostResponseBean` and `ImportAgentPostResponseBean`. This base class have a method `accept(Visitor visitor)`.

```
public abstract class AbstractResponseBean{    
    public abstract void accept(Visitor visitor, AccountEntity entity);
}
```

If your `ResponseBeans` already inherit from an existing abstract class or they implement an existing interface, simply add the `accept` method to that class/interface.

Then, implement `visit` method on each concrete class, as follows

```
public void accept(Visitor visitor, AccountEntity entity){
    visitor.visit(this, entity);
}
```

Finally, create a `Visitor` class, that accept the visit of each concrete `ResponseBeans` class you are interested in. For example:

```
public class Visitor{

    private String getFillName(AccountEntity entity){
        String chineseName = entity.getChineseName();
        String firstName = entity.getFirstName();
        return StringUtils.isBlank(chineseName) ? firstName : chineseName;
    }

    public void visit(AgentPostResponseBean respBean, AccountEntity entity){

        if (StringUtils.equals(respBean.getParentId(), entityId)) {
            respBean.setParentName(getFillName);
        }
        if (StringUtils.equals(respBean.getPosterId(), entityId)) {
            respBean.setPosterName(getFillName);
        }
    }

    public void visit(ImportAgentPostResponseBean respBean, AccountEntity entity){

        if (StringUtils.equals(respBean.getParentId(), entityId)) {
            respBean.setParentName(getFillName);
        }
        if (StringUtils.equals(respBean.getPosterId(), entityId)) {
            respBean.setPosterName(getFillName);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, visitor's private method `getFillName` would be better implemented in `AccountEntity`. This way, your code will be refactored as follows:

```
List<AccountEntity> fillNameAccounts = agentDao.getAgentListByIds(accountIdList);
Visitor visitor = //get instance from some factory or singleton or app context ...

for (T bean : results)
{
    for (AccountEntity entity : fillNameAccounts)
    {
        bean.visit(visitor, entity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the two beans implement an interface and pull the methods in there.

Your beans might like a method

```
  setNameForEntity(String entityId, String nameToSet)
```

as well.

This should compact your code a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you can extract some methods. Maybe this code

```
            if (StringUtils.equals(((AgentPostResponseBean) bean).getParentId(), entityId))
            {
                ((AgentPostResponseBean) bean).setParentName(fillName);
            }
            if (StringUtils.equals(((AgentPostResponseBean) bean).getPosterId(), entityId))
            {
                ((AgentPostResponseBean) bean).setPosterName(fillName);
            }
```

and this code

```
            if (StringUtils.equals(((ImportAgentPostResponseBean) bean).getParentId(), entityId))
            {
                ((ImportAgentPostResponseBean) bean).setParentName(fillName);
            }
            if (StringUtils.equals(((ImportAgentPostResponseBean) bean).getPosterId(), entityId))
            {
                ((ImportAgentPostResponseBean) bean).setPosterName(fillName);
            }
```

can be 2 private methods. Just use the "Extract Method" feature in your IDE. If you use IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio, it's Select the code -> Right Click -> Refactor -> Extract -> Method. If you use Eclipse, it's Select the code -> Right Click -> Extract Method (I think. I haven't used it in a while).